# Question disappeared?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I posted this on [meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24816/question-disappeared) but they couldn't locate my question so I guess I had asked here. I copied my meta question below.

I asked a question like a year ago. It was pretty detailed. Recently I realized I lost my notes on this so I thought I could just go and look the question. The problem is that I cannot find it.

Is there a mechanism that deletes inactive questions? Or am I going crazy here?

It didn't have any answers, comments or votes whatsoever. Does this matter?

EDIT: Apparently it was deleted due to inactivity.

So could a moderator search for a complex analysis question with "Hadamard product" in it's title (or in the text) please?

Comment: Might the title be "Finding singularities from power series", dated 6/23/15? It's a longish post and the words "Hadamard product" appear therein, and there is also a hypergeometric function ${ }_2F_1$ that you're taking a Hadamard product with. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209974/finding-singularities-from-power-series

Comment: YES! Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, will it be deleted again or is it safe now?

Comment: There's a vote to undelete which I can add to, if you want to go public with it again. The software may cause it to be deleted again if there is absolutely no activity on it.

Comment: I don't really think anyone can actually help. I just care that I will be able to see it for at least few days.

Comment: The vote to undelete is from me, cast soon after the question got deleted. My reason for voting to undelete was that the post has nontrivial contents and that it didn't get any negative feedback.

Comment: I voted to undelete too for the same reason as Stefan Kohl.  The last person to vote to undelete may also want to vote up the question so the same thing doesn't happen again.

Comment: @Lucia It's done.

Comment: Thank you a lot. You really saved me from a good amount of work.

Comment: It might be worth updating the meta.math.SE post about the site mismatch and the eventual undeletion.

Comment: Ah, yes. I just did.