# Looking for a missing question on Gelfand-Tsetlin deneration of permuted Schubert varieties

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I could have sworn that, sometime in the last month, I saw a question along the following lines:

> Let $v$ and $w$ be elements of the symmetric group. Let $X(v) \subset
> \mathrm{Flags}(n)$ be the Schubert variety indexed by $v$. Let $w
>  X(v)$ be the image of $X(v)$ under $S_n \subset GL_n$ acting on
>    $\mathrm{Flags}(n)$. What is the limit of $w X(v)$ under the
>    Gelfand-Tsetlin degeneration?

I don't have any new ideas about this question, but I recently learned that Allen Knutson is interested in some related questions, so I wanted to put him in touch with the OP.

I can't find this question anywhere. Was it deleted? Does anyone remember who posted it?

Comment: Maybe it was a dream? I recently had learned that a result which I mentioned for the past three-four years to people, including remembering the title of the paper, the authors and the formulation of the theorem, was all but a dream-generated memory. (The said author had told me that he has no idea how to obtain this result, but if I have even the slightest of ideas, I should let him know.)

Comment: is this the one? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2203/what-is-the-relationship-between-integrable-systems-and-toric-degenerations

Comment: I'd guess that ([meta-tag:searching]) and ([meta-tag:specific-question]) would be a reasonable tags for this meta post. (I cannot edit on meta, that's why suggestion in a comment. I wish I had something more constructive to contribute here. Feel free to flag this comment as obsolete or [ping me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19138/martin-sleziaks-room) to let me know that it can be deleted - after the retagging it would be a completely unnecessary noise.)

Comment: I guess you are aware of this: Mods can search among deleted questions. Other users can only [search for *their own* deleted posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers/13949#13949), which does not help in this instance. If the past cases are any indication, the MO mods do their best to help with requests like yours (two recent examples [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2735/recovering-just-for-me-my-deleted-question-or-answer) or [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2964/question-disappeared).)

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that using [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info), regular users have some limited way to find deleted questions. (Although 10k+ reputation is needed to actually see them.) For example, all deleted questions which were tagged ([tag:schubert-varieties]) can be found [using this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/883845/deleted-questions-with-a-given-tag?tagname=schubert-varieties).

Comment: And since I've commented on a rather old post, I might as well add one more SEDE query. It is possible to restrict this to posts which were deleted within some date range - but viewing all such questions would make a list too long to go through one by one. Probably with [restriction to a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/917338/deleted-questions-between-two-dates-in-a-specific-tag?TagName=ag.algebraic-geometry&Date1=2016-06-01&Date2=2016-09-10) it is possible to make list short enough for this type of search. (But the answer suggests that there was no such post.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to narrow things down, it seems that no question resembling your description has been deleted in the last 6 months.

Comment: Thanks for doing this, Scott. I am confused, but I guess it will remain a mystery, because I have by now fairly thoroughly searched the non-deleted questions and not found it.